# Pandas treats datetime values as float when plotting

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plot

Can somebody please explain me why pandas is treating my Datetime values as floating numbers randomly while plotting my data??

```
for j in range (0, 1):

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(20, 5), sharey='row', gridspec_kw = {'wspace':0.03, 'hspace':0});

for i in range (0,3):
    # Create a figure to plot the results in the grid
    # Have a look at the power consumption of a single vessel for a single day
    APMT_df[(APMT_df['Vessel (IMO No)'] == selected_vessel)
                    & (APMT_df['Time Stamp'].dt.year == 2020) 
                    & (APMT_df['Time Stamp'].dt.month == 2)
                    & (APMT_df['Time Stamp'].dt.day == 6+i)
            ].plot(x='Time Stamp', y = 'Mean Auxillary Power (kW)', ax=ax[i], c='r')

    ax[i].tick_params('x', labelrotation=45)
    ax[i].set_ylim([0, 8000])
    
    ax[i].set_title(selected_vessel)
    ax[i].legend(loc='best')
    ax[i].axhline(y=7500, color='r', linestyle='--')
```

I added the result in the picture

[image: Result plot]

As you can see the floating numbers are unaffected by the axis formatting (e.g. rotation)

Comment: missing imports and many undefined variables, so hard to reproduce the problem...  ask like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The problem is that I have two different dataframes, which have their own datetime column. When I plot these data seperately, it works fine. However when I combine the two plots the date jumps to 1970??